# MFC CRT Order Linker Problem

Tags: mfc, linker, crt

I have exactly the problem described here (i'm getting those linker errors when trying to add MFC to my project):
http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B148652&x=8&y=9

however - if I follow the solution and enter
nafxcwd.lib; libcmtd.lib
into 'ignore libraries' as well as 'additional dependencies', then i'll get a

fatal error LNK1104: Cannot open File "nafxcwd.lib;"

what could be the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to add these libs to Object/library edit box? Or 'additional dependencies' is what used to be "Object/library modules" in Visual Studio 6.0 ?

Comment: Placing the desired libraries in the front of the list at Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies" solved my link errors (undefined symbol afxForceEXCLUDE)

Answer (score 0):

You should add ";$(LibraryPath)" into Project Properties -> VC++ Directories menu Library Directories item.